# Use dropdown in views exposed filter on text fields with entity not node?

Tags: entities, views

A very kind soul posted some code here for a small module that allows [drop down fields in views for text fields on nodes](https://drupal.org/node/1549250#comment-5932296)

I was wondering how I can alter this so it works on an entity I created?

This is the particular field name on this example `field_exact_location`

My entity type is called "site_object"

```
function dd_city_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
$field_id = 'field_exact_location';

// Only alter forms with the necessary field
if (isset($form[$field_id .'_value'])) {
// Build a query to get all node ids having the specified field
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$results = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                  ->fieldCondition($field_id, 'value', 'NULL', '!=')
                  ->fieldOrderBy($field_id, 'value', 'ASC')                    
                  ->execute();

// Attach the field values to the nodes
$nodes = $results['node'];
field_attach_load('node', $nodes, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));

// Add a default so the filter is optional
$options = array('' => '<select>');

// Buld the options array based on the query results, overwriting duplicate entries
foreach($nodes as $nid => $node) {
  $value = $node->field_exact_location['und'][0]['value'];
  $options[$value] = $value;
}

// Alter the field
$form[$field_id .'_value']['#type'] = 'select';
$form[$field_id .'_value']['#options'] = $options;
$form[$field_id .'_value']['#size'] = 1;
}
}
```

[image: screenshot of filter]

Comment: Have you tried to follow the short instructions in your link? Renaming 'field_exact_location' to 'site_object', saving this part and the other one showing, when you follow your link, to files, at last enabling the module?

Comment: Hi Aline - site_object is not a field, it's an entity. That said, it looks like I need to change the entity type from 'node' to 'site_object'. I just don't know about the rest of the code though, for example; '$nid' - what would this be? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) As far as I understand the above code it gets all entities of type 'node' which have the 'field_exact_location', which would be the first thing to change. 
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node') 
to 
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'site_object'). 
Then I would try to change 
$nodes = $results['node'];
field_attach_load('node', 
to 
$nodes = $results['site_object'];
field_attach_load('site_object',

The other $nodes are just variables, which should be changed for clarification but it is not necessary.

Comment: Hi Alina. Let me try this out and let you know how it goes. Thanks very much for your input!

Comment: Nope, that caused quite a few errors. Doesn't the $nid variable need to be changed?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. You have to check 'Expose this filter to visitors', single filter and set the other things the way you like them to be and save the view. Then it should be a dropdown list in your view. It is not something you choose as an operator or anywhere else.

Comment: Yes I know about the exposed views, it does not give me the option to expose a select list (drop down). I think it must be something to do with the view type I am using.

Comment: Added a few screenshots of my test environment and how the modules works for my local installtion. I have the feeling we are talking about different things. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Think I found a solution at last. It works in my local test environment for the exposed filters in views:

```
function dd_city_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $field_id = 'field_selected_field';

  // Only alter forms with the necessary field
  if (isset($form[$field_id .'_value'])) {
    // Build a query to get all node ids having the specified field
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $results = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'model')
                      ->fieldCondition($field_id, 'value', 'NULL', '!=')
                      ->fieldOrderBy($field_id, 'value', 'ASC')                   
                      ->execute();

    // Attach the field values to the nodes
    $entities = $results['model'];
    field_attach_load('model', $entities, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));

    // Add a default so the filter is optional
    $options = array('' => '<select>');

    // Buld the options array based on the query results, overwriting duplicate entries
    foreach($entities as $id => $entity) {
      $value = $entity->{$field_id}['und'][0]['value'];
      $options[$value] = $value;
   }

    // Alter the field
    $form[$field_id .'_value']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form[$field_id .'_value']['#options'] = $options;
    $form[$field_id .'_value']['#size'] = 1;
  }
}
```

I only had to change a tiny bit more, than I posted before.
Summary for the above code:

1. Rename 'field_selected_field' to your field. Example: If it is called 'city',
   then rename it to 'field_city'.
2. Change 'model' to the name of your entity. In your case 'site_object'
   These are the places:

   - $results = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'model')
   - $entities = $results['model'];
   - field_attach_load('model', $entities, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));
3. Save the file to your module, upload it and enable it in Drupal.

A few screenshots of my test environment:

Here my example configuration for a view with an entity named 'model' with the field 'selected_field'.
[image: view settings]
[image: exposed filter settings]

If you go to the respective view (in my case /modeltestview), you get the following (the screenshot is only part of the screen). The left part is the starting part,you get the right part if you click on the dropdown list. To show there actually is something in the dropdown list.

[image: example view]

Comment: No errors but I still don't get the option to use drop downs unless I got for grouped filters which aren't appropriate. Can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Currently the module only works for exposed filters in views. Where do you want the dropdown list to work? Probably it only has to have a different function name.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. The view is exposed but it does not let me choose a select list. If I switch the filter to 'grouped' that option shows up but is no use there.

Comment: @Rich This module changes the text field to a dropdown list, if you add an exposed _filter_ to your view. So users can filter which elements to show them. And it does it on all views which are using this field as an exposed filter. If that is not the thing you want, you have to explain a bit more where exactly you want the dropdown list.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, what I am saying is - it isn't working. I installed it, cleared the cache and it does not change my exposed filter as it should. The only way I see a drop down select list is when I change the filter to grouped, but this is pointless as I don't want to group text of course.

Comment: Yes I know this but it does not work. I want exactly what you say you have done but it simply does not work when I implement the code. I will attach a screenshot of what I see. Maybe it is something to do with my view. Thanks.

Comment: My view looks identical to your however it won't function the same!! Very annoying, thanks for all your help.