# Use dropdown in views exposed filter on paragraph text field in node view?

Tags: views, 8, paragraphs

I have seen [Use dropdown in views exposed filter on text fields with node->title?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184775/use-dropdown-in-views-exposed-filter-on-text-fields-with-node-title) but I need to use there a field from a paragraph field of the node.
Let's say the paragraph field in the node is called field_pdfs and the field in the paragraph is called field_pdf_title. (node -> field_pdfs -> field_pdf_title).
I tried the following code:

```
function pdf_app_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

// If not the view we are looking, move on


// Query nodes
$storage = Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');
$nids = $storage->getQuery();

// Gather published artist nodes and sort by title
$nids = $nids->condition('type', 'library')
 ->condition('status', 1)
 ->sort('title')
 ->execute();

// If there are no nodes, move on
if (!$nids) {
 return FALSE;
}

// Start building out the options for our select list
$options = [];
$nodes = $storage->loadMultiple($nids);

// Push titles into select list
foreach ($nodes as $node) {

$result = $node->get('field_pdfs')->referencedEntities();
foreach ($result as $paragraph) {
  if ($paragraph instanceof Paragraph) {
    $value = $paragraph->field_pdf_title;
 $options[$value] = $value;
  }


 }
  }

// Start building out our new form element
 $form['field_pdf_title']['#type'] = 'select';
$form['field_pdf_title']['#options'] = $options;
$form['field_pdf_title']['#size'] = 1;
 }
```

Comment: You almost had it, needs to be `$value = $paragraph->field_pdf_title->value;` When getting an Entity/Node's title just happens to not require the `->value` part, but fields do.

Comment: Yes thank you it is working!

Comment: Also viable: `$paragraph->get('field_pdf_title')->getString()` or `$paragraph->get('field_pdf_title')->first()->getValue()` (getValue returns an array without `first()` first)

Comment: Thank you it is working! The only problem is that it shows me all the paragraphs and not just the ones belonging to the current node. Any leads?